# Very strange - what's the limit of $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{sin(x)+cos(x)}{x}$?

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions

What's the limit of: $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{sin(x)+cos(x)}{x}$ ?

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \left (sin(x) + cos(x) \right) = sin(0)+cos(0) = 1
$

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} x = 0$

$\Rightarrow \frac{1}{0} \Rightarrow$ L'Hôpital's rule is needed

$f'(x) = cos(x) - sin(x)$

$g'(x) = 1$

$\Rightarrow $

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \left (cos(x) - sin(x) \right ) = cos(0) -sin(0) = 1-0 = 1$

So 1 will be the limit? No way because as it looks like, the denumerator will be too small and thus the complete function will go towards $\infty$ for $x \rightarrow 0$.

This is very confusing for me :S

Maybe the mistake is using L'Hôpital?

Comment: You can't use Lhopital here.

Comment: Thought so... But why not?

Comment: Because $1/0$ is not an indeterminate form. Here, this limit does not exist, which can be verified by graphing (please do as part of the learning process)

Comment: Lhopital only works in certain situations. Can you recall what they are?

Comment: $1/0$ indicates not a need for l'Hôpital, but a diverging result. l'Hôpital is for $0/0$ and $\infty/\infty$.

Comment: 0/0, 0/1, $\infty*0$, $\infty / \infty$, $\infty - \infty$ ?

Comment: @cnmesr There are couple of indeterminate forms that can be "converted" into $0/0$ or $inf/inf$ situations on which L'Hospital can be used. You mentioned couple of them, but there are still few more, for example $1^0$

Comment: @cnmesr: $0/1$ is unambiguously $0$. No l'Hôpital required.

Comment: @cnmesr You cannot, a priori, use l'Hopital on $\infty-\infty$.

Comment: You are missing all the intuition here.  What is $1/(.00000000001)?$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

l'Hopital's rule only works for the limits "$0/0$" and "$\infty/\infty$".

To compute this limit try this:
$$\frac{\sin x+\cos x}x=\frac{\sin x}x+\frac{\cos x}x$$

Comment: The numerator has limit $1$, the denominator has limit $0$; no need to split: the limit is $\infty$ for $x\to0^+$ and $-\infty$ for $x\to0^-$.

Comment: Doesn't seem to help:
$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{sin(x)}{x} = \frac{0}{0}$ and
$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{cos(x)}{x} = \frac{1}{0}$ can use L'Hôpital for first but not for second...

Comment: @cnmesr L'Hopital is not meant to be used on this problem, the limit does not exist either.

Comment: But how would you write that down then? As I did in the comment now?
The first will go to 1 and the other to $\infty$, so in total it will all go to $\infty$..?

Comment: No, I would say DNE, which means does not exist.

Comment: @cnmesr Sorry I thought it was lim as x approaches infinity, not 0... I deleted my post and I will delete this comment too :)

Comment: No need to say sorry, I appreciate every answer to my question and thank you all very much :)

Comment: @imranfat, from which point would you say that? Right after the given hint from ajotatxe? I'm really scared to explain it wrong in the exam and get (-)

Comment: @cnmesr After you wrote down your conclusion $1/0$. No need to split the limit either

Comment: L'Hospital's Rule is not restricted to only $0/0$ and $\infty/\infty$.  In fact, it applies to $\text{anything}/\infty$ for which the "anything" need not even exist.  [See the note here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#General_proof).

Answer (score 2):

Because the question is not in indeterminate form i.e. it's not $\frac{0}{0}$.

Comment: There is a little more that that though...(didn't downvote)

Comment: I give up vote so it's normal again. 
Not fair to negate someone for trying to help imo.